# Powershell send-mail message, how to put line break in body variable

Tags: powershell, scripting, html

I am searching for a string in multiple files within a folder. 
If I get that string, then I would like to email all these folders which have this string. I have figured all that out and have adjusted the way I want my format.

The issue is when I send the email, the content shows up all in 1 line. 
I want this text to be broken word by word. Below is the code:

```
$find = Get-Childitem –Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*\Web.config | Select-String -Pattern "abc..config" 
$boards = $find.Path | Out-String 

[array]$split = $boards.Split("\") 
$count = $split.Count

$out = for ($i=0; $i -le $count; $i++) {
    $split[$i+3]
    $i = $i + 3
    }

$out2 = $out | Out-String

Send-mailmessage -from "" -to "" -subject "Test" -body $out2 -BodyAsHtml -priority  High -dno onFailure -smtpServer
```

The issue is that the body shows up like below:
ABC ABC2

But, I want the body to be:

```
ABC
ABC2
```

I have also tried getting the output to a text file and using -Raw with gci:

```
$find = Get-Childitem –Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*\Web.config | Select-String -Pattern "abc..config" 
$boards = $find.Path | Out-String 

[array]$split = $boards.Split("\") 
$count = $split.Count

$out = for ($i=0; $i -le $count; $i++) {
    $split[$i+3]
    $i = $i + 3
    }

$out | Out-file -FilePath C:\Test.txt 
$body = Get-content C:\Test.txt -Raw 


Send-mailmessage -from "" -to "" -subject "Test" -body $body -BodyAsHtml -priority  High -dno onFailure -smtpServer
```

I did use Out-String and -Raw with gci and I am on V4. Not sure what I am missing. When I output the file, it is correct format with line breaks but not when I email. I would prefer not creating a text document and just use the variable in the body.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of your message body is NOT HTML, yet you are using `-bodyAsHtml` on send-mailmessage.  Your body is just text, and when you specify `-bodyAsHTML` that causes the line breaks to be removed.  Removing `-bodyAsHtml` should fix your problem.

Within an HTML document, line breaks are represented by `<P>`, `<BR>`, and are only preserved when they appear inside of `<PRE>`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you much! I pretty much ignored it.